# custom action for a nested resource without adding to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, action, link-to

This is probably really simple but I have a nested resource lets say:

map. resources :book, :has_many => :pages

I write an action called "turn" that increases page.count by 1. How do I call this action using a link_to? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where your `page.count` comes in. In Railish, you would find `pages.count` (note the 's'). Further, `count` (and also `size`) is a read-only attribute on arrays and hashes et.al. provided by ruby that returns the number of elements. You don't set `count`.

Next, I'm not sure where your `turn` action is supposed to live, on the Book or the Page? And what is supposed to happen after it does what it does? Finally, a route is what makes an action an action -- without it, it's just a function.

For a moment, we'll assume you are trying to store the number of times a Page in a Book has been visited. It would be a better idea to have an instance variable called `reads` or `times_viewed` etc. in your Page model. Assuming your Book model is using restful routing, in Book's `show` action, you create an instance variable of the Page model being viewed and increment its `reads` attribute before rendering the view.

If you are trying to make a link sort of how 'Like' works in Facebook, meaning you want to update a record in a table without sending the user to a different page, you'll need to use `link_to_remote`* and some javascript. In that case, I'd just refer you to the Railscasts on that subject.

*I think as of Rails 3, `link_to_remote` became just `link_to` with `:remote => true`.